# How to attach a JWT to a JMS message?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, jms, activemq-classic

We need to send a JWT token alongside each JMS message. Other than packing it in the payload itself, I am unsure if attachments or headers are possible within JMS and/or ActiveMQ message structure.

Looked into ActiveMQMessage but did not find attachments or headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at the JMS documentation, specifically [the documentation on messages](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) which says:

> JMS messages are composed of the following parts:
>
> - Header - All messages support the same set of header fields. Header fields contain values used by both clients and providers to identify and route messages.
> - Properties - Each message contains a built-in facility for supporting application-defined property values. Properties provide an efficient mechanism for supporting application-defined message filtering.
> - Body - The JMS API defines several types of message body, which cover the majority of messaging styles currently in use.

In short, *use a property*. Attachments don't exist in JMS.

The aforementioned documentation details the necessary API call(s) to set a property.